# Hide slides from presentation and from handout

Tags: handout

Can anyone tell me how to hide certain slides from both presentation and from handout mode at the same time, i.e. combining `handout:0` and `presentation:0`?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also the comment environment (comment package).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the best way:

```
\begin{frame}<handout:1|presentation:all>
```

or to hide both places:

```
\begin{frame}<handout:0|presentation:0>
```

Combinations work of course.